# Prevent .apk installation if Unknown Sources is checked

Tags: android, apk

Can I prevent an .apk from being installed if unknown sources is checked?

Comment: Could you clarify? This is a very broad question..

Comment: Sure..sry 
I have an app which is distributed outside google play. Embedded at the ROM level as a system app. With apps like APKInstaller, an user can export the .apk and install it on any device.

What Im trying to accomplish is have the .apk not be installed if unkown sources is checked...thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS) to see if user has permitted installations from unknown sources

Comment: great..thnx!!...I will give that try

Comment: How are you going to check it if your app is not installed yet? If you check it in your app, then the user could install your app, then uncheck the unknown sources box then run the app. Granted that would make it annoying to use the app, but it's certainly circumventable.

Comment: Well, in essence Im trying to generate an App, that when exported to .apk via apps such as APKInstaller, the .apk exported is not install-able. 
If .apk wont install if cause "unknown sources" is checked, it wont install if its unchcked since the system wont allow non-market apps installed. 

The app will be embedded at the ROM level as a system app